# How does this redirection after a here-document work?

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, heredoc

```
ftp -v -n <<! > /tmp/ftp$$ 2>&1
open $TARGET_HOST
user $TARGET_USER $TARGET_PWORD
binary
cd $TARGET_PUT_DIR
put $RESULTS_OUT_DIR/$FILE $FILE
bye
!
```

I inderstand that <<! is a "here-document" and is passing the commands to ftp until it reaches the delimiter "!" but I can't seem to wrap my head around this redirection:

```
> /tmp/ftp$$ 2>&1
```

Could someone please explain what is happening here?

Comment: The _here_ document start at the **next** line. All redirections - including `<<` - can basically appear anywhere in the command line. The `>` is an output redirection for stdout and `2>` is an output redirection for stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the heredoc could be listed last without affecting what happens. Heredocs are traditionally written last but the `<<NAME` but can actually be written anywhere within the command. The order of `<<` relative to the two `>` redirections doesn't matter since the former changes stdin and the latter change stdout and stderr.

It'd be clearer if it were written:

```
ftp -v -n > /tmp/ftp$$ 2>&1 <<!
    ...
!
```

Second, to explain the output redirections:

- `> /tmp/ftp$$` redirects stdout to a file named `/tmp/ftp1234`, where `1234` is the PID of the current shell process. It's an ad hoc way of making a temporary file with a relatively unique name. If the shell script were run several times in parallel each copy would write to a different temp file.
- `2>&1` redirects stderr (fd 2) to stdout (fd 1). In other words, it sends error messages to the same file `/tmp/ftp$$`.